# Maven stage of build failing in Azure DevOps.Used a self hosted agent for building sample java but getting "Unhandled: EPERM: operation not permitted"

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Used a self-hosted agent for building sample java but getting `##[error]Unhandled: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd'`

Please help me troubleshoot [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXUqQ.png):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. The root cause was due to authentication issue.

I was using a self-hosted agent and my Maven was asking for authentication but it was unable to autheniticate.

How I resolved this error :

I installed maven in D drive and changed the env variables such that it points to D drive then it worked fine.